# How do I configure TortoiseHg to open a file in the right program based on its extension?

Tags: windows, tortoisehg

I'm using TortoiseHg v2.2.1 with Mercurial 1.9 in WindowsXP. How do I configure TortoiseHg to view a file based on the application Windows has associated with its extension?

For example, if I have a .docx file in the repository and I'm looking at its revision history, I'd like `View at revision...` to open the selected revision in MS Word. Likewise for other binary file types like ppt and xls, which I can't view using the default text editor or kdiff3.

Can I leverage that Windows already knows what program to use to open certain types of files or will I have to manually configure each file type of interest within the Tortoise config files?

I've found several SVN scripts in the `TortoiseHg\diff-scripts` folder that look like they solve a similar problem for diffing binaries rather than simply viewing them, but those don't seem to be activated and I'm not sure what if anything I need to mod in the [`MergePatterns.rc`](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/1.0/common.html#word-diffs) or `Mercurial.ini` files to make this all work.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911135/specify-editors-in-mercurial)

Answer (score 2):

To make "View at Revision" use whatever program is associated with the file's extension, try this trick: In the "Global Settings" in the "TortoiseHg" section, enter `start ""` as "Visual Editor". Note the empty `""`. This is necessary so that `start` will not use the file name, which gets passed in quotes by TortoiseHg, as the window title.