# VSCode as editor in TortoiseHG?

Tags: mercurial, visual-studio-code, tortoisehg

How do I configure TortoiseHG to use VSCode as my editor?

The [TortoiseHG editor setting](http://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#tortoisehg) does not list VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This is now included in TortoiseHG 4.4.1 as one of the pre-configured tools. Select it in ''TortoiseHG Settings'' -> ''TortoiseHG'' -> ''Visual Editor'': `vscode`.

---

[Adjusting this answer for VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911135/specify-editors-in-mercurial) seems possible with something like `[tortoisehg] editor = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"`.